# PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jackrabbit

I downloaded the [Jackrabbit Standalone Server](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/standalone-server.html), and when running the java -jar command on the jar, the app loads up fine to localhost, but when trying to access populate.jsp in the webapp, i get this error:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /populate.jsp. Reason:
>
> PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP PWC6199: Generated servlet
>   error: The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 275 in the jsp file: /populate.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The type java.lang.CharSequence
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The import java.util.Arrays cannot
>   be resolved
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 275 in the jsp file: /populate.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The type java.lang.CharSequence
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files
>
> at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)
>   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437) at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Any Ideas? (I've also tried some fixes by loading it into IntelliJ, but they didn't work.)

Comment: To run JSP you should use Tomcat or Jetty. See  http://tomcat.apache.org/

Comment: In fact on their FAQ page http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/frequently-asked-questions.html  they point to their downloads page http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html where they have a war file. That war file will create a  Jackrabbit web app in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Java 8 but using Java 7 works fine.

```
java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.11.3.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

the jackrabbit-standalone-2.14.3.jar didn't work on jdk 8 , but it works file on jdk 7

Answer (score 0):

Bug is known and fixed, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-4183. Release TBD.